# Drupal 7 Add jQuery File to all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have looked into drupal's main page here: https://drupal.org/node/171213, but am still getting an error.

In my .info file I added the code:

```
stylesheets[all][] = template.css
scripts[] = megamenu.js
```

I understand that the style sheet is not needed. I just put it in there for reference to how it looks in my code.

I checked in my Google Chrome Web-Dev settings and it isnt even loading a the .js page, which leads me to believe that I did something wrong in the .info file. Does anyone have any ideas on where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you clear the theme cache?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - Haha, so funny story... I told myself I wouldn't forget that part... And then I forgot to do that part. Thank you!

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment above,  clearing the theme cache fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

$form['#attached']['js'] = array(drupal_get_path('module', 'billing') . '/billing.js' => array(
      'type' => 'file',
      ));